# HTTP Internal error 500 on Tomcat during load testing

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, automated-tests

Our team is performing load testing on our Tomcat based application (Spring Core + JSF + Oracle) which uses a Apache web server for forwarding requests. The load testing tool (WAPT) is trying to simulate 3 users accessing a single search page with the same parameters being searched. However it results in a failure with an HTTP Internal Error 500 for most runs. When the same test is done manually, this issue doesn't happen. 
So is there any  additional resources that the tool may be blocking? The server logs do not disclose much in terms of the specific issue there might be in the code, not even a stack trace. But is there some way to retrieve that?
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue on the Database side. Certain DB parameters were not configured in the newer environment due to which there high parsing & executions on the SQL side.